# Spring Boot: Web.xml and embedded server jar

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to convert a legacy spring-mvc app to Spring boot (in order to have a self contained JAR enabling easier upgrade to Java-8).

I see no reason to use replace my existing web.xml file with code as the code looks like configuration and web.xml is more established.

Is it possible to use my existing web.xml in a Spring Boot application (in embedded JAR mode)?

Edit: I also want to avoid using @EnableAutoConfiguration

Thanks

Comment: So you want spring-boot but don't want to use it... Then why bother, just create your own executable file with embedded tomcat and be done. instead of trying to use a framework and next try to work around the same framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, thanks to Mecon, I'm slightly closer. I had to remove the ContextLoaderListener in the web.xml; also had to import the xml Spring config even though it was referenced in the contextConfigLocation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:/webapp-base.xml"})
public class WebApp {

    @Autowired
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Autowired
    private MediaConfiguration mediaConfig;

        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
            JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            factory.setContextPath(serverProperties.getContextPath());
            factory.addConfigurations(new WebXmlConfiguration());
            factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {
                    List<Handler> resourceHandlers = getResourceHandlers();
                    Handler original = server.getHandler();

                    HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
                    Handler[] array = getHandlers(original, resourceHandlers);
                    handlerList.setHandlers(array);

                    server.setHandler(handlerList);
                }
            );
            return factory;
        }

    private List<Handler> getResourceHandlers() {
        return mediaConfig.getMappings().stream().map(m -> {
            ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler(m.getUrlpath());
            ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
            resourceHandler.setResourceBase(m.getFilepath());
            contextHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);
            return contextHandler;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Handler[] getHandlers(Handler original, List<Handler> resourceHandlers) {
        ArrayList<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        handlers.add(original);
        handlers.addAll(resourceHandlers);
        return handlers.toArray(new Handler[resourceHandlers.size()+1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Spring-Boot to have a self-contained JAR, all you really need is Embedded Tomcat, or Jetty.

Create a class with `public static void main(String[] a)`, and this Class will be used when the Jar is "executed" by `java -jar myWebapp.jar` command.

In the `main` method, you can fire up the Embedded Tomcat or Jetty, and make it load your webapp by referring to existing web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, but still not clear. How do I refer to the existing web.xml?